# Refresh JDesktopPane not working

Tags: java, jlabel, repaint, jdesktoppane

I want to create a preview of the file I read with a specified number of lines. My code works fine, the problem is that if I choose another number of lines, the JDesktopPane is not refreshing and it's overwriting the previous lines.

My code looks like this:

```
previewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {


                        try {

                            if(Integer.parseInt(nrLines.getText()) < 20) {
                            for(int i=0; i< Integer.parseInt(nrLines.getText());i++){
                            previewLabel[i] = new JLabel(" ");
                            previewLabel[i].setText("Line nr. "+(i+1)+": "+previewList.get(i));
                            previewLabel[i].setBounds(20,575+25*i,700,300);
                            previewLabel[i].setVisible(true);
                            desktopPane.add(previewLabel[i]);                               
                            }
                            desktopPane.repaint();
                            }   
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Maximim number of lines is 20 !");
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println("Please enter a integer value !");
                        }

                        }
                });

                desktopPane.add(previewButton);
```

Here is how it looks after I choose another number of lines:

[image]

Thanks in advance for help !

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, it seems that every time `actionPerformed()` is called, you add new `previewLabel`s to the `desktopPane`. You could try keeping track of what you've added (or inspecting the children of `desktopPane`), and removing old labels before adding new ones.

Alternatively, instead of creating new labels, perhaps you could replace the contents of the old ones.

Example (I haven't used your code, but it shows the two approaches I'm thinking of):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Test {

   static JLabel labelToReplace;
   static JLabel labelToUpdate;

   private static JLabel newLabel(String s) {
     JLabel l = new JLabel(s);
     l.setBounds(30, 160, 200, 40);
     labelToReplace = l;
     return l;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) { 
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
     frame.setSize(300, 300);
     JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
     frame.setContentPane(desktopPane);

     // This one we will update.
     labelToUpdate = new JLabel("Test label");
     labelToUpdate.setBounds(30, 120, 200, 40);
     desktopPane.add(labelToUpdate);

     // This one we will replace.
     desktopPane.add(newLabel("Another"));

     JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("Refresh");
     btnRefresh.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener() {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             labelToUpdate.setText(new Date().toString());

             desktopPane.remove(desktopPane.getIndexOf(labelToReplace));
             desktopPane.add(newLabel(new Date().toString()));
           }
         }
     );
     btnRefresh.setBounds(30, 50, 100, 70);
     desktopPane.add(btnRefresh);

     frame.show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you help me with a way how could I remove or replace the old ones with new ones ? I tried everything I knew..

Comment: Thank you so much ! I was really stucked at this. I knew I did something wrong but didn't knew how to fix it. thanks again